# Issue to run Splash image with memory configuration

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, haproxy, scrapy-splash

I am using splash version 3.0 to be used to scrap along with python. I have docker compose file configured for splash and haproxy images. When I start docker using this docker-compose file with splash configured using "mem_limit: 1400m" I am getting below error, while commenting out this configuration make it working fine.

> ERROR: for aquarium_splash1_1  Cannot start service splash1: b'oci
> runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process
> caused "process_linux.go:261: applying cgroup configuration for
> process caused \"failed to write 1 to memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes:
> write
> /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/1688a046edbf131e8abaffcf934a000f5f3d28b3baaee36dd8f9af0fb1800b48/memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes:
> operation not Creating aquarium_splash3_1 ... error

I have enough memory configured on my server.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G       5.7G       9.9G       308M       129M       4.8G
-/+ buffers/cache:       795M        14G
Swap:         2.5G        33M       2.5G
```

Below are the docker-compose.yaml file and haproxy file content

**Docker-Compose file**

```
version: '2'

services:
    haproxy:
        image: haproxy:1.7
        ports:
            # stats
            - "8036:8036"

            # splash
            - "8050:8050"
        links:
            - splash0
            - splash1
            - splash2
            - splash3
            - splash4
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro

    splash0:
        image: scrapinghub/splash:3.0
        command: --max-timeout 3600 --slots 200 --maxrss 1000 --verbosity 1
        expose:
            - 8050
        mem_limit: 1400m
       # memswap_limit: 1800m
        restart: always
```

**haproxy file**

```
global
    # raise it if necessary
    maxconn 512
    # required for stats page
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy

userlist users
    user user insecure-password userpass

defaults
    log global
    mode http

    # remove requests from a queue when clients disconnect;
    # see https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-option%20abortonclose
    option abortonclose

    # gzip can save quite a lot of traffic with json, html or base64 data
    compression algo gzip
    compression type text/html text/plain application/json

    # increase these values if you want to
    # allow longer request queues in HAProxy
    timeout connect 3600s
    timeout client 3600s
    timeout server 3600s


# visit 0.0.0.0:8036 to see HAProxy stats page
listen stats
    bind *:8036
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats show-legends
    stats show-desc Splash Cluster
    stats uri /
    stats refresh 10s
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth    admin:adminpass


# Splash Cluster configuration
frontend http-in
    bind *:8050

    # http basic auth
    acl auth_ok http_auth(users)
    http-request auth realm Splash if !auth_ok
    http-request allow if auth_ok
    http-request deny

    # don't apply the same limits for non-render endpoints
    acl staticfiles path_beg /_harviewer/
    acl misc path / /info /_debug /debug
    acl genengnews query -i -m sub genengnews
    acl gen_host req.body -i -m sub genengnews

    use_backend splash-us if genengnews || gen_host
    use_backend splash-cluster if auth_ok !staticfiles !misc
    use_backend splash-misc if auth_ok staticfiles
    use_backend splash-misc if auth_ok misc

backend splash-cluster
    option httpchk GET /
    balance leastconn

    # try another instance when connection is dropped
    retries 2
    option redispatch
    server splash-0 splash0:8050 check maxconn 200 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4
    server splash-1 splash1:8050 check maxconn 200 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4
    server splash-2 splash2:8050 check maxconn 200 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4
    server splash-3 splash3:8050 check maxconn 200 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4
    server splash-4 splash4:8050 check maxconn 200 inter 2s fall 10 observe layer4

backend splash-misc
    balance roundrobin
    server splash-0 splash0:8050 check fall 15
    server splash-1 splash1:8050 check fall 15
    server splash-2 splash2:8050 check fall 15
    server splash-3 splash3:8050 check fall 15
    server splash-4 splash4:8050 check fall 15

backend splash-us
    balance roundrobin
    server splash-0 45.79.135.34:8050 check fall 15
```

Can you please help me to understand why with "mem_limit: 1400m and memswap_limit: 1800m" I am having issue to run splash which was working sometime back

Comment: Run `docker info` and check for potential warnings regarding unsupported features on your running kernel. For more information, read https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/, more precisely the second paragraph after title.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think capability is disabled by kernal because this was working earlier, but I have restated a server and it stopped working. And I even don't see any WARNING message with `docker info` command. Some last line output of this command is:  
**bold**  `Total Memory: 15.6GiB
Name: debian
ID: ZVAX:C2EI:U2WC:EQUL:ATSN:G7RF:4JG6:F2VJ:TBOB:VBXW:DVC7:HDK6
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false`